# Windows Ethernet showing "Network cable unplugged" when connected to Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, redhat, ethernet, ifconfig

I currently have a Windows 10 machine connected to a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 6.10 machine by Cat 5 Ethernet cable.

I plug an Ethernet cable from `eth2` port on the Linux machine to `Ethernet` on Windows machine.

I run `ifconfig eth2 down` on the Linux machine to take down the network connection. The Network Connections window on the Windows Machine show that `Ethernet` is connected to an Unidentified network. I cannot ping the static ip address for `eth2` however.

If I run `ifconfig eth2 up` on the Linux machine to bring up the network connection Windows shows `Ethernet` as "Network cable unplugged'. When running `ifconfig` on the Linux machine the following shows:

```
eth2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr __:__:__:__:__:__
        inet addr: 192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
        Interrupt:17
```

If I ping `192.168.1.11` on the Windows machine I get the message `Destination Host Unreachable`.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how you configured your interfaces on both sides.

From your ifconfig on Linux side it appears that you configured it with a static IP 192.168.1.11/24. What about Windows side? Is the interface also configured to have some static IP in the same network? E.g. 192.168.1.12 with netmask 255.255.255.0?

BTW, most modern Ethernet interfaces feature automatic polarity detection, so the need to have a crossover cable is quite rare these days.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to touch IP configuration until you see link is UP

1. Check if cards are blinking
2. Try replacing the cable
3. Try lowering link speed with duplex change with ethtool (windows:network settings GUI)

   > ethtool -s eth2 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need a cross-over cable - an ethernet cable where the receive terminal from one side connects to the transmit terminal on the other, and vice versa. Or just use a modern hub or switch as an intermediary - most automatically switch the direction automatically. Plug both machines into the hub or switch, and they should be able to communicate from their static IPs just fine.

Comment: this is my first thought too, though whoever downvoted this answer before maybe had some other awesome idea.. still, getting the peers to talk is another matter. is samba still the norm?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Cross-Over cable (Pin 1,2 to 3,6 and visavi).
And don't forget to manualy set up your IP configuration (Gateway is not needed) in the same subnetmask. There is now no DHCP server between.